# Ruby: undefined method '>' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

Currently working on a binary search algorithm for Ruby, but am running into an error when comparing the middle array element with n.

Code Below:

```
def b_search(n, arr)
    middle = arr.length / 2
    first = 0
    last = arr.length - 1

    while first <= last
        middle = first + last / 2
        if arr[middle] == n
            return true
        elsif arr[middle] > n
            last = middle - 1
        else
            first = middle + 1
        end
    end
    false
end

nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
target = 4

if b_search(target, nums)
    puts "Target Found"
else
    puts "Target Not Found"
end
```

The error evidently happens in the while loop at the

`elsif arr[middle] > n`

line, but I'm not sure why. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use the [built-in binary search](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch)? There's also [a variant which returns the index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch_index) rather than the element.  Your if-statement would then be `if nums.bsearch { |x| target <=> x }`.  That would be faster and likely more reliable than reinventing the wheel with your own implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It occurs because `arr[middle]` is `nil` and `nil` has no method `>` defined on it.

Consider that

```
middle = first + last / 2
```

is equals to

```
middle = first + (last / 2)
```

and you probably meant

```
middle = (first + last) / 2
```

so use the parentheses because `/` has a higher precedence